# Redirect Bigquery Data to Prediction

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery, google-prediction, data-science

We are developing a POC in Google's Spreadsheets.

There are some configurations, but in a nutshell it downloads data from BigQuery and redirects it to Prediction.

Our Bigquery tables have over to 41Mb, with is not allowed/supported by Spreadsheets.

We thought in download packages of 5Mb of data from Bigquery. 
Although Predicition API provides methods for [**insert**](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/prediction/v1.6/) lots of data, the [**update**](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/prediction/v1.6/) method allows to upload only one line/instance.

Is there any way to redirect Bigquery data straight to Prediction?

The main three functions involved are:

```js
/**
 * this function downloads data from Bigquery
 * for a given table, it receives the columns supposed to be downloaded
 *
 * @params
 * - modelName // the new prediction model name
 * - columns // an array of columns
 * - table // the table name
 * - dataset // the dataset name
 */
function createPrediction(modelName, columns, table, dataset) {
  try {
    var rows = simpleQuery(columns, table, dataset);
    var rowsL = rows.length;
    var trainingL = parseInt(0.9 * rowsL, 10);
    var training_instances = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < trainingL; i++) {
      training_instances.push({'output': rows[i].f[0].v, 'csvInstance': rows[i].f[1].v});
    }
    
    var resource = {'id': modelName, 'trainingInstances': training_instances};
    var insert_reply = Prediction.Trainedmodels.insert(resource, c_projectId);
    
    c_modelName = modelName;
    
    Browser.msgBox('Insert reply:' + insert_reply, Browser.Buttons.OK);
  } catch (err) {
    Browser.msgBox('ERROR: ' + err, Browser.Buttons.OK);
  }
}

/**
 * this function should receive a dataset name, a table name and some columns' names
 * it is supposed to return the "SELECT [COLUMNS] FROM [DATASET.TABLE]"
 *
 * @params:
 * -
 */
function simpleQuery(columns, table, dataset, projectId) {
  projectId = projectId || c_projectId;
  return getQuery("SELECT " + columns.join(",") + " FROM [" + dataset + "." + table + "]", projectId);
}

/**
 * this function should return the result for a given query
 *
 * @params:
 * - query // the query to be evaluated
 * - projectId // the googles's project id
 */
function getQuery(query, projectId) {
  var request = {
    query: query
  };
  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
  var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;
  // Check on status of the Query Job.
  var sleepTimeMs = 500;
  while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
    Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
    sleepTimeMs *= 2;
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);
  }
  // Get all the rows of results.
  var rows = queryResults.rows;
  while (queryResults.pageToken) {
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId, {
      pageToken: queryResults.pageToken
    });
    rows = rows.concat(queryResults.rows);
  }
  return rows;
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct connection between BigQuery and the Prediction Api at this time, but both integrate with Google Cloud Storage.

For training new models, you can export BigQuery data to GCS as a CSV file, then insert that file into the Prediction Api.

For updating existing models from BigQuery data, you are going to have to do more work since the Prediction api supports single-row inserts to existing models, but BigQuery only provides bulk export to GCS or ranged reads via `bigquery.tabledata.list`. You will need some processing to extract the data from BigQuery and insert it one row at a time to your Prediction model.

Using Google Apps Script to access BigQuery from within a Google Spreadsheet opens up a lot of easy integration options, but there are also processing limits imposed by Apps Script, like maximum file upload sizes... You might find other frameworks more flexible. Would [Cloud Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) work for you? How about [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/)?